# Get or Post for REST method in MVC4?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking at defining a set of REST api's using MVC4 and need advice on what to call my methods:

I have two related methods that can return a single value

```
string referenceNumber SOMEMETHOD(string accountCode, string accountNumber)<br/>
string referenceNumber SOMEMETHOD(string fullAccount)
```

Both return a value, but don't really create anything (in CRUD terms) that is persisted - it's fire n forget.

The second `SOMEMETHOD` appears best suited to a GET request, but the first one looks more applicable to a POST - however it doesn't actually POST anything?

(I'm coming from a WCF/SOAP background where I would have `GenerateReference(...)` methods)

Comment: Apols - I know not part of the original question - but what would I call a "validation" method?  e.g. send through a value and ge tback true/false if it is valid?  Is that a GetValidation() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing that prevents you from defining them both as Get methods if that is a concern. 
You can name them `GetReferenceNumberByAccount` and `GetReferenceNumberByCodeAndNumber` or some other descriptive name (shorter perhaps).

In Asp.Net MVC you are free to name your methods whatever you want - as long as it's a valid C# method name and you have valid routes for your actions.

Comment: Perhaps I am reading things wrong - I though the controller had only Get, Put, Post, Delete methods?  Is it more a case of the methods must START with Get, Put, etc. ?

Comment: In Asp.Net MVC you don't have that limitation. You can give your actions (methods) arbitrary names. You might be thinking of WEB API. The Previous version Web API had conventions like that, but in the latest version (WEB API 2) even that's become more flexible

Answer (score 0):

in Web API Use This for Get or Post

```
[GET("")]
string referenceNumber SOMEMETHOD(string accountCode, string accountNumber)

[POST("")]
string referenceNumber SOMEMETHOD(string fullAccount)
```